# Which are the best open source tools/solutions for digitizing road networks?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, road, free-software

Which are the best open source tools/solutions for digitizing road networks?

I was thinking on tools/plugins for QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

The [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) (OSM) editor [JOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM) is a great tool for digitising. Although it is specifically developed for editing data in OSM it can save data as .osm or GeoJSON files which can then be converted to other GIS formats (e.g. using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)).  This export facility converts it into a good general purpose digitising package.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS does it, as it can digitize with (pseudo)topology. Beside the core tools to digitize, there are a number of extensions that can help the user.